# why "set parent to with automatic weight" can't work on mirror?

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I add bones on my created figure. I want to connect the body to the bones. I click on both and use  "set parent to with automatic weight", but the mirrored half part of body doesn't cover the bones. Why is that?

[image: [Modifier]

[image: automatic weight]

[image: the problem]

Comment: Settings seams fine. Are the rotation of the model and the rig the same (0,0,0 for Eurler and 1,0,0,0 for Quaterion)?

Comment: Yea they are the same.

Comment: Anyone can help...?

Comment: Or you may apply the mirror modifier first and the apply the automatic weights

Answer (score 0):

I just found out one way...First cancel mirror modifier, Second go to edit mode click A to select all, Third shift-D duplicate and S to scale on one axis by -1.Then use shift-J to connect both side.

[image]

Then it works for "automatic weight" process.

Comment: If you didn't want the modifier to be active, then you just could apply it and then skin your mesh to the armature. It would be much faster then your workaround. So the question remains unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the flipped normals,before assigning the bones to the mesh ,just go into edit mode and select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> then do the automatic weight

When the normals are on the wrong side you will see the darker color in the shading mode